# Gradient function in matlab gives unexpected result

Tags: matlab

I find that gradient function in matlab gives me different answer from my expectation.

I tested this dataset

```
a = [0.337961000000000   0.394426000000000   1.083110000000000;
0.337977000000000   0.394627000000000   1.084470000000000;
0.337972000000000   0.394768000000000   1.085870000000000;
0.337950000000000   0.394923000000000   1.087260000000000;
0.337949000000000   0.395092000000000   1.088510000000000]
```

According to the way used to calculate gradient

v(2,:) = (a(3,:)-a(1,:))/(2*dt)

where dt = 1/240;

I expect v(2,:) can be

```
0.001319999999998   0.041039999999994   0.331200000000011
```

while gradient function (gradient(a)/dt) give

```
1.0e+02 *

0.135960000000000   0.895791600000000   1.655623200000000
```

Can anyone please help to see what is wrong here? Thank you.

Comment: why computing the `gradient(v)`? don't you mean `gradient(a')` ? more precisely its second column

Comment: Thank you for pointing out it. I have updated it.

Answer (score 2):

you are looking at the wrong orientation of the gradient, you need to use the second output of gradient.

For example:

```
[~, fy] = gradient(a);
fy = fy / dt;
fy(2,:)

ans =

     0.0013    0.0410    0.3312
```